# $modal.open(), problema com declaração do parâmetro "controller"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Estou tentando abrir um modal através da view, pelo método showModal(), o problema é que recebo um erro referente a declaração do controller "editCrtl", o qual é muito estranho, pois já esta carregado no index e está perfeitamente criado. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Stacktrace:

> Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ng/areq?p0=editCrtl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Códido do controller da view:

```
app.controller('listCtrl', function($scope, Crud, filterFilter, $modal) {

    $scope.veiculos = Crud.getList();

    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.veiculos.length;
    // Itens por página
    $scope.entryLimit = 6;
    $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);

    $scope.$watch('search', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.veiculos, newVal);
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
    }, true);

    $scope.remove = function(veiculo) {
        var index = $scope.veiculos.indexOf(veiculo);
        if (index != -1) {
            Crud.remove(index);
        }
    }

    $scope.showModal = function(veiculo) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation : true,
            templateUrl : './app/view/vehicle-register.html',
            controller : 'editCrtl',
            resolve : {
                veiculo : function() {
                    return veiculo;
                }
            }
        });

    };

});
```

Controller do Modal

```
app.controller('editCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, veiculo) {    

});
```

Comment: na declaração do teu controller está escrito assim: `editCtrl` e na declaração do teu modal está assim: `editCrtl`

Comment: Complementando, no link do erro diz o seguinte: `Argument 'editCrtl' is not a function, got undefined` ou seja, `"editCrtl é um argumento indefinido`, com isso você conseguiria achar o problema  sem precisar elaborar a questão =D

Answer (score 1):

Não está encontrando o controller "**editCrtl**", acredito que você tenha escrito errado o nome. Não seria "**editCtrl**"?